# db.collection('name').find({something: "1"}) not returning the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve a document from a collection in mongodb. 
I am using the following command

`db.collection('audioFile').find({format: 1})`

But this is not returning me the format document ({format : "wav"})
instead is returning a large json file.

I tried running the same command in mongo shell, and it gives me correct output. But I am trying to do it in JS(node.js) it doesn't work.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Could you share how the document looks in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use projection for this.

```
db.collection('audioFile').find({}, {projection: {format: 1}})
```

you can put 0 if _id still persists like this

```
db.collection('audioFile').find({}, {projection: {_id: 0, format: 1}})
```